# Show that if K1⊃K2⊃· · · ⊃Kj⊃ · · · is a nested downward sequence of compact sets and U is an open set...

Tags: real-analysis

**Show that if K1⊃K2⊃· · · ⊃Kj⊃ · · · is a nested downward sequence of
compact sets and U is an open set which contains ∩j Kj, then U contains one of the sets Kj.**

I can visualize the decreasing sequence of compact sets K and was going to approach by showing another sequence of compact sets L, where Lj=∅ (not sure if that is against being compact).  Then, Uj's = the increasing L's and now Uj's are the total set. Then, by compactness, finite subcollection of Uj's cover L1 and Uj becomes a ⊃ of L1, meaning Lj=∅.  Then Lj=∅ or U⊃Kj.

**Please give details on the best way to approach this problem, as I am not that experienced on the topic and am still learning.  Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

Prove by contradiction. Assume this does not hold, then $(\bigcap_{i=1}^nK_i)\cap U^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^n(U^c\cap K_i)\neq\emptyset,\forall n$. Since $U$ is open, $U^c$ is closed, and it follows from compactness of $K_i$ that $K_i\cap U^c$ is compact. Since every finte intersection of $\{K_i\cap U^c\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is nonempty, it then follows that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty(K_i\cap U^c)\neq\emptyset$, which contradicts the fact that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty K_i\subset U$.